# Semiconductors: question about electric dipole transition selection rules between and within bands

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, dipole

Here is roughly what I understand about selection rules for electron transitions in a semiconductor quantum well:

- If it's from conduction band to valence band, the rule is $\Delta n = 0$.
- If it's from one sub-band to another (i.e. within the conduction band), the rule is $\Delta n = \pm 1$

The qualitative reason I was given is:

- Matrix element $M$ for electric dipole transition has odd parity
- Therefore if the integral $\int \psi_2 M \psi_1 dr$ is to be nonzero, the wavefunctions $\psi_2$ and $\psi_1$ must have opposite parities
- Conduction band is s-type and valence band is p-type, so the parities are opposite for equal $n$, so $\Delta n = 0$
- Adjacent states have opposite parities within the conduction band, so $\Delta n = \pm 1$

My confusion:

This argument does not seem to constrain the selection rule enough. It looks as though you could have $\Delta n$ be any even number for the former case, and any odd number for the latter case. Is there another effect which suppresses dipole transitions for large changes in $n$, so we only have to consider the $0$ and $\pm1$ cases?